# preprogrammed interactive application for testing FM4-176L-S6E2CC-ETH board features

Tags: microcontroller

I am facing a problem with FM4-176L-S6E2CC-ETH board. I am not able to test this microcontroller using the preprogrammed interactive application on CMSIS-DAP virtual communication port terminal.

The documentation says that you connect the board to PC and open the CMSIS-DAP virtual communication port terminal and press enter on your keyboard.

I am not getting the testing environment by following this procedure. Any suggestions on how to access that application will be appreciated.

I have attached the snapshot of the CMSIS-DAP virtual communication port environment.[image: Observe the baud rate and other necessary settings]

Comment: Did you press "Enter"? -- "_the pre-programmed production test software provided by CMSIS-DAP virtual communication port_" sounds as if you think that the virtual communication port provides this test software. Well, it cannot, this software needs to be in the program memory of your device. It is just talking via this port, if it runs.

Comment: "The FM4 S6E2CCA microcontroller comes pre-programmed with an interactive 
a pplication to test all of the on-board features using a virtual communication port to send message prompts, input test parameters, and output test results." This has nothing to do with "production test software" as mentioned in the title

Comment: @thebusybee thankyou for your reply, Yes, i have pressed enter after connecting the board.  I know that software shd be in the program memory of the device. sorry that phrase sounded different.

Comment: @markus-nm Thank you for your reply, by production test software i meant the same interactive application to test board features. i am not able to run that appplication even after pressing enter.

Comment: If this application is in flash, it runs right after power-up. So the issue is that you cannot connect. Did you follow the quick start guide step by step? Especially, did you install the driver? Does the device show up in the hardware manager if you connect it?

Comment: @thebusybee yes device is recognized and even i am able to debug codes using Keil uvision5.

Comment: What code shows the debugger, your own? -- If so, you have flashed the device with your own, and I'd assume that the pre-flashed test program was overwritten. -- If you did not load own code to the device and you can use the debugger, you have all possibilities to debug the issue. You might need some time to make sense of the instructions you will see.

Comment: @thebusybee, yes, i also think that pre-programmed application is overwritten, is there any way to restore it?

Comment: You need to find the binary of this application, and then flash it the usual way.